# Passing session identifier as a query string parameter

Tags: session, cookies, security, session-cookies

Are there any security practices/techniques/considerations when, for example during (long/continuous) polling or normal requests between clients and server, session ID is sent/passed to the server as a query string parameter instead of a value stored in a cookie?

I can think of session hijacking or sniffing when someone would stole this session ID from query string and use it to impersonate himself, but I think the same thing can also happen to cookie value (I guess this can be prevented only by using https).

Comment: *"same thing can also happen to cookie value"* - FYI, this is not true, cookies are not subject to the same risks.

Comment: FYI [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) - "HTTP cookies used to maintain a session on many web sites can be easily stolen by an attacker using an intermediary computer or with access to the saved cookies on the victim's computer (see HTTP cookie theft)".

Comment: yojimbo87, I don't follow what you are getting at with your last comment.  Did you read the answers here?  I'll say it again another way, in case my initial comment was too terse.  Query parameters can be leaked in ways that cookies will not be.  Query parameters are subject to additional risks that cookies are not subject to.  Just read the answers below to see some examples of that (e.g., Referer, server logs).

Comment: @D.W.: you quoted in your comment part of my original text where I said that session ID stored in a cookie can also be a target of session hijacking and you said that it's not true (which according to many sources it is true and I only meant by the last sentence of my question that session ID can be hijacked in both cases, therefore I didn't meant that all the other query string risks also apply to cookies). At least that was my initial understanding of your first comment. If you meant by "not true" other risks which are in described in answers then I'm ok with it.

Comment: I know this is late to the game, but @D.W. is essentially correct, in that the risks exposed by keeping session information in a cookie store are more-or-less a strict superset of the risks exposed by keeping the session information in query string parameters. There are still some risks that are common to both, but in most cases, the risks are much better mitigated in a well-implemented cookie store than in any sort of query string parameter solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When passing session tokens as URL params two things you specifically need to worry about is browser history and server logs. URL params are typically stored in both and are then exposed in plaintext whether or not you use SSL.

They can also accidentally be exposed by end-users if they were to copy and paste from the browser to Twitter, for example.

It doesn't sound like you are talking about normal browsing. But if you are, then using URL params is strongly discouraged.

You also mentioned polling, but in my experience, if a cookie is available then it is sent along in the polling request removing the need for it to be in the URL.

And for server to server traffic you still need to worry about IDs being saved in the server logs.

The only argument I have ever heard for using session tokens in URL is to accomodate users who have cookies disabled. I prefer to pretend like those users don't exist.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. I want to pass session (or I would rather call it client) IDs in the url because I want to create a long poll server for the case where two (or more) different applications are using the same poll server and there are different users connected through these applications. If I use session IDs stored in cookies then there might probably be a collision of identities since the same cookie would be sent back to server during the polling.

Comment: If your session tokens are long enough and sufficiently randomized then I would think that the chance of two of them being the same, while technically possible, would be astronomical. If you are still concerned about it, then perhaps you could have the request include a applicationid (which would be fine in the URL). Then use the applicationid combined with the session token to differentiate.

Comment: I mean the main problem is in cookie name which has the same name for the poll server, not the unique session IDs. When user from App A connects his session ID is set to this cookie value. When user from App B is connected his session ID is overwritten in the existing cookie because it has the same name.

Comment: Are all of these apps and the polling service running from the same domain?  On different hosts?  For example appA.domain.com, appb.domain.com, polling.domain.com. If so, then you should be able to create the cookies so that they do not conflict and overwrite each other by using the domain attribute when setting your cookies.

Comment: Apps are on different domains and they all communicate with the same poll server (poll server can listen also on different subdomains in order to overcome browser specific parallel connection limitations, but the backend program is the same). Reason why the cookie name is the same is that when poll request comes to the polling server it doesn't know which cookie it should check for the session ID since the request (and it's session/client) is not identified until the session ID is retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the risks that Jason mentions, a third risk is that the session token might be disclosed to other sites via the Referer: header.  I would not recommend sending the session token as a query string parameter.